# Ansible security best practices for monitoring

Tags: security, monitoring

I have several servers at home. I would like to have one computer that will monitor activity on those and notice me if something is wrong. For that reason I install ansible there. In order to have maximum possible security, the user that ansible will use, will have permissions only for things that it should do and no more. However, I encoutered to a problem, I will explain it on this simple case.

Let's say we want to know the temperature of `/dev/sda` on `host1`, for the sake of simplicity I will use `hddtemp` for gathering the data, and we will use user `monitor` for monitoring. The tool `hddtemp` requires privileged user to execute it so I allow it in sudoers:

```
%monitor  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/hddtemp
```

But access is still denied because device one needs to access `/dev/sda`. On Debian 11 these block devices are in the group `disk`.

```
brw-rw----   1 root   disk      8,   0 sep  4 21:31 sda
```

So I add user `monitor` to this group. But the error message has changed from this:

```
/dev/sda (read) access denied
```

to this:

```
/dev/sda access denied
```

I have two questions:

1. Is my approach legit or am I overthinking it
2. If it is legit, how can I grant my user `monitor` the access to the temperature of my HDD? Is the access to block device `/dev/sda` enough or I need to give it something more to read the temperature?

Comment: For starter `%monitor` is the syntax in sudoers to grant permissions to the (members of a) *group*  monitor rather than a specific user. - Second is the monitor user actually executing  `sudo  /usr/sbin/hddtemp`  (because typically ansible does privilege escalation differently than you might expect see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general )

Comment: And in general running an existing (agent based) monitoring solution might be easier to set up and maintain than completely rolling your own.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Ansible, except that is how the author wants to automate the checks. It may as well be listed as a BASH question.

Answer (score 1):

A configuration management suite like Ansible is a good match for updating and maintaining the configuration on a server, but it's not a good match for monitoring a server.  Configuration management does periodically check the config of the server and *invoke commands to change the config*, but that's only when the "desired configuration" for that server changes.  With monitoring, you want the (monitoring) commands to be invoked even when the server configuration has not changed.

Also, monitoring wants to invoke commands at different intervals.  Some commands every 30 minutes, and other commands every 5 minutes.  Often with a failure triggering configurable re-trys every minute until 3 or more consecutive tries fail, before sending an alert.  Configuration management doesn't want to run multiple status check/change procedures at different intervals, more like one check/change every 30 minutes or less often.  In this additional way, config management suites are not a good match for monitoring.

As comments have already suggested, it's better to do your monitoring with a software suite that's designed for monitoring.